# Looping through table column values in a model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I achieve looping through a database table's values for a specific column within a model?

Give a model Hub.rb, here is a method I have:

```
# Methods
def self.update_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    # Updates only the new articles from last run
    updated_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)
    add_entries(updated_feed.new_entries) if updated_feed.updated?
end
```

I then have a table in my database called "feeds" which has a schema of: id, name, description, url.

What I want to do is loop through each row in the "url" field from the feeds table and do it in the Hub.rb model.  It will be an outer wrapper of the function shown above and will pass the feeds.url field from the feeds table into the "feed_url" argument in the Hub.rb method.

Something like this:

```
# Methods
def self.update_feed
  loop do 
    feed_url = LOOP THROUGH URL COLUMN DATA
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    # Updates only the new articles from last run
    updated_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.update(feed)
    add_entries(updated_feed.new_entries) if updated_feed.updated?
  end
end
```

This way I can just call Hub.update_feed from the terminal and it will go through all of the URLs I have listed in the feeds table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Feed.where("url IS NOT NULL").each do |f| 
  Hub.update_feed(f.url) 
end
```

Comment: Great thank you. I am always confused what you can put in a model vs. the logic in the view/controller. They look exactly the same, which I guess is a good thing.